# Filter xml data based on keys listed in text file with `xsltproc`

Tags: xml, xslt

I an XML file which I want to filter based on data in a text file

XML file

```
<customers>
    <customer id="1">
        <name>Alfreds Futterkiste</name>
    </customer>
    <customer id="2">
        <name>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</name>
    </customer>
    <customer id="3">
        <name>Antonio Moreno Taquería</name>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Text file with keys

```
1
3
```

The XSL should now `apply-templates` for `@id='1' or @id='3'` like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=" customer-with-id-in-file " />
```

How can I express `customer-with-id-in-file`. It is possible to wrap the key file with XML stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "*It is possible to wrap the key file with XML stuff*"? Ideally, you would have something like:

```
<customers>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>3</id>
</customers>
```

as the second file.

If that's not possible, and all you have is say:

**file2.xml**

```
<xml>1
3</xml>
```

you could do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

*(requires `libxslt` or another processor that supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` function)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="key-file" select="'file2.xml'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customer[@id=str:tokenize(document($key-file)/xml, '&#10;')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

> I have total control over the input file.

Well then you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customer[@id=document($key-file)/customers/id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

assuming you are using the structure shown above. No extension functions are required for this.

Comment: @michael.hor275k I have total control over the input file. Can I get the key-file name file2.xml as parameter to xsltproc?

Comment: Yes, you can - in the same way as shown above (it needs to be a *path*, not a filename).

Comment: the condition @id=... is really powerful